# I have been looking for solution to get sum of multiple columns(for a single row) in Mysql to get total of every hour for electricity invoice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote below query to get sum but it is showing(something progressing) total as null for couple of records. It is showing 1064 error at line 4 when I include all records like below.

```
select 
Metering0,Metering1,Metering2,Metering3,Metering4,Metering5,Metering6,Metering7,Metering8,Metering9,Metering10,Metering11,Metering12,
Metering13,Metering14,Metering15,Metering16,Metering17,Metering18,Metering19,Metering20,Metering21,Metering22
total = (Metering0+Metering1+Metering2+Metering3+Metering4+Metering5+Metering6+Metering7+Metering8+Metering9+Metering10+Metering11+Metering12
+Metering13+Metering14+Metering15+Metering16+Metering17+Metering18+Metering19+Metering20+Metering21+Metering22)
from ireneene_calculationdb.invoice_template_year
```

Comment: This is kind of problem is symptomatic of (very) poor design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, you're missing a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is showing total as `null` for couple of records

Probably, at least one of the columns has a `null` value for those records. In MySQL (and most other RDBMS), `1 + null` yields `null`. You can work around this with `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(Metering0, 0) + coalesce(Metering1, 0) + coalesce(Metering2, 0) + ...
```

> It is showing 1064 error at line 4

`column_alias = <expression>` is not valid MySQL syntax (this is a SQL Server syntax). You should put the column alias after the expression, optionaly preceeded by keyworkd `as`, like:

```
coalesce(Metering0, 0) + coalesce(Metering1, 0) + coalesce(Metering2, 0) + ... as total
```